# How to have a view that relates resources based on routes?

Tags: routes, resources, relationship, react-admin, custom-pages

Currently I have a `<TabbedShowLayout>` presenting resource data and related data. I want a view to make relations with resource. I was trying to have a tab that changed its contents based on route and for that used `Switch` and `Route` but no success with that. The base route was supposed to be something like `resource/id/show/related-model-tab/` and for adding relation something like `addremove` was added to the previous route.

I want to have a component to render on the 1st route, and another in the 2nd. Since RA doesn't support a feature like this yet, should I use `Switch` and `Route` components from React Router, or should I use the customRoutes in order to show relation add/remove components outside the tabbed layout?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is neither. RA doesn't support nested routes in `Tab` in v2.1.1 or under, the best solution to preserve the behaviour is to have the `Tab` change its content only based in a flag. For example if flag is not active, show a list of related items, if flag is active show the possibility to add or remove related items.

Even without the route specification it's probably a more dynamic solution than have a custom route for every related model addition or removal. If there were too many model relations it could be a cumbersome to have a `customRoute` to each relation.